# how to open an element using the stored value in the cookie

Tags: jquery

how to open an element using the stored value in the cookie. I was able to retrieve the cookie value from the clicked element in the first page but then how can i use the cookie value to .show an element in my page?

First Page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //jquery toggle menu
        $(".product-contents").hide();
        $("div.product-header").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
        });

        //setting the clicked element value in the cookie
        $("#product-list div").click(function() {
            var index = $("#product-list div").index(this);
            $.cookie("product_name", index);
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Toggle Menu

```
<div id="product-list">
<div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-header">sampletest</div>
    <div class="product-contents" style="display: none;">
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/18">flat black matte</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/19">flat black matte</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/30">product two</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/24">In augue tellus</a></div>
</div>
<div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-header">sampletest</div>
    <div class="product-contents" style="display: none;">
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/33">flat black matte1</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/34">flat black matte3</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/35">product two4</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/36">In augue tellus55</a></div>
</div>
<div class="product-wrapper">
    <div class="product-header">sampletest</div>
    <div class="product-contents" style="display: none;">
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/66">flat black matte3</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/77">flat black matte3</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/88">product two4</a></div>
    <div class="product-subheader"><a href="/printing/sampletest/99">In augue tellus2</a></div>
</div>
```

second page

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert($.cookie("product_name")); //cookie value is displayed


    $(".product-contents").hide();
        $("div.product-header").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
        });

    });
```

how can i use the cookie value to open the selected element from first page to open or .show() the element in the second page

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#product-list div").get( $.cookie("product_name") ).show();
```

Though I think you may mean `$("#product-list > div")` both where you set and get the cookie.

Comment: still didn't work here's the code i used $(document).ready(function(){
   alert($.cookie("product_name"));
   $(".product-contents").hide();
   $("div.product-header").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
   });
   
   $("#product-list div").get($.cookie("product_name")).show(); 
  });

Comment: put it after the .hide() if you want it open right away, not in the click handler.

Comment: also, close all your product content div tags with `</div>` and put the `>` in at least the selectors for .click